# Nested relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three models in following manner of relationship:

**Tour.php**

```
class Tour extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\TourCategory', 'category_id');
    }

    public function region()  
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Region');
    }
}
```

**TourCategory.php**

```
class TourCategory extends Model
{
    public function tours()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Tour', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

**Region.php**

```
class Region extends Model
{
    public function tours()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Tour');
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get all tours with specific tour category from every region.

**For example**
*Get all hiking tours from Rocky Mountain Region, Yellow Stone, Yosemite*

I've tried to the following code:

```
public function trekRegions( View $view)
{
    $category = TourCategory::where('slug','=','hiking')->first();
    $tours = $category->tours()->with('region')->get(['region_id']);
    $regions = $tours->pluck('region')->unique();
    $view->with('tregions',$regions);
}
```

I want to print all tours name below the region name in Mega Menu Navigation Bar but the above code does allows me to print the region name but also prints the tours from other categories as well.

**My code in frontend**

```html
@if(!empty($tregions)) @foreach($tregions as $region)
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <strong class="title sub-link-opener">{{ $region->name }}</strong>
  <ul class="header-link">
    @foreach($region->tours as $tour)
    <li>
      <a href="{{ route('frontend-tourDetail',[$tour->slug]) }}">{{ $tour->title }}</a>
    </li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
</div>
@endforeach @endif
```

Comment: Furthermore: What would be the query if I need get all hiking tours from all existing regions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your particular requirement.

filter `Regions which has hiking tours` and eager load `hiking tours`

```
$regions = Region::whereHas('tours', function ($toutQuery) {
    $tourQuery->whereHas('tourCategory', function ($categoryQuery) {
        $categoryQuery->where('name', 'hiking');
    });
}) // filter to match your requirements.
->with([
    'tours' => function ($toursQuery) {
        $toursQuery->whereHas('tourCategory', function ($categoryQuery) {
            $categoryQuery->where('name', 'hiking');
        });
    }
]) // load matching tours.
->get();
```

Comment: What would be the query if I need get all hiking tours from all existing regions ? i.e Rocky Mountain, Yosemite

Comment: I guess `hiking tours` is name of a `Tour Category`. if so. `$tours = Tour::whereHas('tourCategory', function($query) { $query->where('name', 'hiking tours'); })->get()`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but your query only shows hiking and its specific category i want to display hiking as category & its respecting region

Comment: this query returns `all the tours which belongs to hiking` if you want to eager load their particular `region` with them. `Tour::whereHas('tourCategory', function($query) { $query->where('name', 'hiking tours'); })->with('region')->get()`

Comment: Tour has only category relationship so query will be Tour::whereHas('category', function($query) { $query->where('name', 'hiking tours'); })->with('region')->get()

Comment: @TharakaDilshan Thank you for the suggestion. I think that you guys didn't get my query to the point. I've updated my question. Could you please go through it.

Comment: let me guess, You want `all the regions which has hiking tours assigned to it`

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm looking for. As I'm printing data in nav bar

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one query

```
$tours = Tour::whereHas('category', function($c) {
    $c->where('slug', 'hiking');
})->whereHas('region', function($c) {
    $c->where('title', 'Rocky Mountain Region');
})->get();
```